# Drupal add multiple text fields to a webform component

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Using drupal webforms, is it possible to add multiple fields within a single webform component?

I'd like the end-user to be able to an an address component instead of adding each address line individually for each webform.

Answer (score -1):

I've always found web form to be a little limited in terms of customization. When I need to control form layout explicitly I use another piece of software called `FormTools`.

http://www.formtools.org/